# UIImageView frame same as scaled UIImage inside it (with Aspect Fit)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I'm using `UIImageView` with **Content Mode** set to **Aspect Fit**. `UIImageView` resizes correctly my image but it doesn't change own frame after resizing even there is no constraints set.

#### What I need:

1. I need `UIImageView` to resize own frame according image inside. I've configured image view at Storyboard.
2. I need to layout again other objects at view because UIImageView's size is changed.

#### What I've tried:

I've created:

- UIViewController (white background) → UIImageView (gray background) → sample image inside it.
- Constraints: leading & trailing constraints set to zero, Y constraint is set to align UIImageView vertically.

As you see after image scaled correctly UIImageView's frame is still has incorrect size (gray background).

[image: /Users/sorix/Desktop/example.png]

I've tried to set UIImageView size manually:

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let newSize = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: backgroundImageView.image!.size, insideRect: backgroundImageView.frame)
        backgroundImageView.frame = newSize
    }
```

In that example code I've calculated image size and set frame size to image's size. I don't know if it is better way so I don't need to use AVFoundation's methods.

Problem: other object is place incorrectly because UIImageView's size changed and constraints are invalid now.

That methods doesn't work for me:

```
self.view.setNeedsLayout()
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Even I will call my UIImageView size calculation at `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` other constraints is still using old UIImageView's size.

#### Questions

1. How to change UIImageView's size correctly? Maybe I can do it without code? Maybe I need to play with Hugging/Compression? I've tried something but got no luck.
2. How to force view to **recalculate other constraints** so they will use new UIImageView size? For example I can put red square at the top of UIImageView, but after UIImageView has been resized by my method, red square still will be at the old UIImageView's position.

Comment: A width long rectangular image won't scale up to a height long frame. You can choose to use `scaledAspectFill` if you want to cut off some of your image - or another one of the `contentMode` settings if you don't mind if the aspect ratio is distorted.

Comment: @sdasdadas, I'm happy with Aspect Fit, I just need to eliminate top and bottom borders = resize vertically UIImageView. But I have problem with other constraints so.

Comment: Bad news. While not an *exact* duplicate of one of my first answers here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40220451/how-can-i-use-uiimageview-with-aspectfill-and-alignment-to-the-top/40221741#40221741), it's close enough that my recommendation stands - either change the specs you are working on, or try setting the image view's background to transparent. Sure, it *can* be done. But you are setting yourself up for major headaches down the road trying to dynamically resize UIImageViews based on their image.